# Kafka in Docker using Confluent CLI doesn't work

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, confluent-platform, confluent-cli

I'm trying to set up a local Kafka cluster on my Mac (*Intel-based, running macOS Sonoma 14.3.1*) by following the [Confluent developer guide](https://developer.confluent.io/get-started/dotnet/#kafka-setup). However, when I try to start the cluster, it **doesn't do anything**.

I installed `Confluent CLI` via Homebrew:

```bash
brew install confluentinc/tap/cli
```

And added the following to my `~/.bash_profile`:

```bash
# For Confluent
export CONFLUENT_HOME="/usr/local/Cellar/cli/3.48.1"
export PATH=$PATH:$CONFLUENT_HOME/bin
```

I started Docker Desktop `v4.27.1`.

I then tried to start the Kafka broker using:

```bash
confluent local kafka start
```

I got the following message with no further information or any port details:

```
The local commands are intended for a single-node development environment only, NOT for production usage. See more: https://docs.confluent.io/current/cli/index.html
```

When I subsequently checked the status of the services with:

```bash
confluent local services status
```

It said the cluster was NOT running.

```bash
The local commands are intended for a single-node development environment only, NOT for production usage. See more: https://docs.confluent.io/current/cli/index.html
As of Confluent Platform 8.0, Java 8 will no longer be supported.

Using CONFLUENT_CURRENT: /var/folders/zn/z1znabcd70vcabcd0cv87y1j0000gn/T/confluent.092959
Connect is [DOWN]
Kafka is [DOWN]
Kafka REST is [DOWN]
ksqlDB Server is [DOWN]
Schema Registry is [DOWN]
ZooKeeper is [DOWN]
```

Can someone please help with setting up local Kafka cluster on a Mac via `Confluent CLI`? I'm surprised the docs aren't good on something this popular.

---

**Edit:** Also asked this question in [Confluent Community Forum](https://forum.confluent.io/t/kafka-in-docker-using-confluent-cli-doesnt-work/10184?u=akhanalcs).

**Edit2:** It started working after I restarted Docker Desktop and reran the command! ‍♂️

[image]

Comment: You're running brew inside docker? It's not meant to be ran that way  If you want to run all the services, the documentation suggests Compose or Kubernetes with separate containers. Running everything from one container is an anti pattern

Comment: @OneCricketeer Hi, No I'm not running brew inside docker. They're separate. I'm just trying to run Kafka inside docker *via* `Confluent CLI` [as mentioned in their docs](https://developer.confluent.io/get-started/dotnet/#kafka-setup) under Local setup.

Comment: I wasn't aware that command required Docker. That's why I was confused. In any case, there should be log files written inside that CONFLUENT_CURRENT folder. Otherwise, as mentioned, using Docker Compose is designed to be more reproducible https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/platform-quickstart.html

Answer (score 0):

> However, when I try to start the cluster, it doesn't do anything.

You should see the Docker image downloading, followed by output including the ports that you can use to connect to Kafka. The `Plaintext Ports` value is the port to use in the `bootstrap.servers` endpoint.

Do you not see any of that if you let `confluent local kafka start` run?

> When I subsequently checked the status of the services with:
>
> `confluent local services status`
>
> It said the cluster was NOT running.

The `confluent local services ...` commands aren't intended to work with `confluent local kafka start` so this is expected. The `confluent local services ...` commands need a local install of Confluent Platform while `confluent local kafka start` is Docker-based and intended to be easier to get going. In the future the two sets of commands will likely get consolidated into one approach to avoid confusion.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the answer. It started working _after_ I restarted Docker Desktop and reran the command. I updated this information in the question under **Edit2**.